# how to write a loop that only changes value in object

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

i m catching from firebase storage 3 different images (link).

I want create three object with key->value pair. Key is always the same (url) and value is link from storage. i m trying loop url: but it only display me last link

```
  let linkArray = []
  let linkObject = {}
  
  this.img.forEach((el) => {
    linkArray.push(linkObject)
    linkObject['url'] = el
  
    console.log(linkObject)
  })
```

results from first code is :

- 0: {url: 'thirdLink'}
- 1: {url: 'thirdLink'}
- 2: {url: 'thirdLink'}

]

In code below is what I want to achieve, but it is written in vue and it would be a problem if I entered the fourth image (link) in the firebase storage

```
[
  { 
    link: {
       url: 'firstLink',
       scaledSize: { width: 30, height: 30 },
    },
    check:true
  },  
  {
    link: {
       url: 'secondLink',
       scaledSize: { width: 30, height: 30 },
    },
    check:true  
  },  
  {  
    link: {
      url: 'thirdLink',
      scaledSize: { width: 30, height: 30 },
    },
    check:true  
 },
],
```

scaledSize and check are always the same so you can ignore them.

Any suggest, advice

Comment: So this is about vue list rendering? Can you show the relevant template code? Are you using `v-for` or something?

Comment: you log linkObject which is always overwritten by the last value

Comment: Yes i m using v-for and vue2-google-maps.  I want my images (link from firebase storage) to be markers on google maps. But hassanqshi wrote down  code what i need. i every time overrighted. thank you guys :D

Answer (score 2):

With your log you are not logging the array. Push the structure you want and log the array.

```
  let linkArray = []
  
  this.img.forEach((el) => {
    linkArray.push({ 
    link: {
       url: el['url'],
       scaledSize: el.scaledSize,
    },
    check:true
  }
)
  })

  console.log(linkArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this. Hope this might help

```
let linkArray = []

this.img.forEach((el) => {
  let linkObject = {}
  linkObject['url'] = el
  linkArray.push(linkObject)
  console.log(linkObject)
})
```

Comment: its not "might help" it helped me. Thank you man :D

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, objects are a reference type. So every time you push a new object into the array you should create new it (to avoid overwriting the old object you created initially, causing only display last link). See more at https://dmitripavlutin.com/value-vs-reference-javascript/

You can edit it like this:

```
        let linkArray = []
        
        this.img.forEach((el) => {
            let linkObject = {'url': el}
            linkArray.push(linkObject)
            console.log(linkObject)
        })
        console.log(linkArray);
```